# I want to vs I need to vs I would like

Tags: phrase-usage, auxiliary-verbs

What is the difference between these expressions :

- I want to do something
- I need to do something
- I would like to do something

Specially when you want to ask for help (In doing something).

and is "I'm wanting ..." right?

Answer (score 3):

[Wants are often distinguished from needs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Want)
A need is something that is necessary for survival (such as food and shelter), whereas a want is simply something that a person would like to have.

'I would like to . . .' states your preferred or desired action, and should usually be followed by the infinitive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't form your answer which of these is correct : I need help to do my homework. I want help to do my homework. (and for sure I'll survive even if I don't do my homewrk :) )

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What exactly you don’t understand?

Answer (score 1):

What you may *need* is something you just can't make do without objectively, whereas what you may *want* is most of the time within your mind.

So, if you *need to do* something, doing this is either vital for you in general (to survive, to be physically or mentally healthy, to feel secure, to not starve or freeze, etc.) or absolutely necessary, not only preferable, in particular circumstances or by the force of circumstances.

What you *want to do* is generally entirely a matter of your personal choice or preference. No matter how strong your desire to get it is, in any case, it won't do any harm to you if you fail to get it.

In *"I need some help"* and *"I want some help"* you may choose the former when you are sure that without someone else's help, you won't be able to do something, and you choose the latter when someone's help may (as you see it) make the completion of what you started doing easier, quicker, more entertaining, etc.

As for *"I'd like to get some help"* said to someone who's around, to me it sounds like a hint to have help offered.